# Interpolating arrays with different vectors

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I have multiple arrays that I need to identify and interpolate to a set number. the set number will be the 'length?' of the biggest array. I need to  How could I identify each array length and create a loop to interpolate each array to that specific length? Sorry if I am not providing enough detail.

Comment: Could you past an example of arrays and what you want to do with them (e.g A = [...], B = [...], RESULTS = [...])

Comment: Yes, I'll try my best. I have two input arguments for a code that will interpolate each array within the arguments. A and B are cells that are 176x1 and 382x1 cells, respectively. These arrays are of all varying lengths, anywhere from 36x1 double to upward near 250x1 double. I am trying to plot out each array on a figure, and need to interpolate each array in the arguments. So I need help having MatLab take each array, determine the longest one, and then interpolate all other arrays to that determined length. I can do the plotting portion. Hope this clarifies, I'm a beginner at this stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
A = rand(10,2);
B = rand(20,2);
C = rand(5,2);

%find max length, for you cell array you want: max(cellfun(@(x) length(x), MyCellArray))
n = max([length(A), length(B), length(C));    

%repeat for each, i.e. loop through the cell array
x = A(:,1);
y = A(:,2);
m = min(x);
M = max(x);
d = (M - m) / n;
xi = m:d:M;
Ai = interp1(x, y, xi);
```